# What is the point of an optional method in a protocol?

Tags: objective-c, protocols

If I'm going to have to call "respondsToSelector:" on the object anyway, what does defining a method as optional actually do for me?

For exmple, let's say I have some code like this

```
id<MyProtocol> myObj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
if([myObj respondsToSelector:@selector(aMethod)]){
  [myObject aMethod];
}
```

As long as "MyClass" implements "aMethod", won't this code run exactly the same wether or not MyProtocol defines "aMethod"?

I can see the use of defining this optional protocol purely from a code readability standpoint, but don't understand if it actually has any effect from a technical standpoint (other than making it unnecessary to declare the method in the header).

Answer (score 8):

Pretty much what it says on the tin: it relates to optional functionality. If your `aMethod` contains *essential* functionality in order for your application to work it should be `@required`. Otherwise if it provides additional functionality for the implementer to do other things, but its absence won't negatively affect the way it should work (i.e. it's alright that the implementer doesn't respond to the `@selector(aMethod)` selector), you can make it `@optional`.

You see this *a lot* in view delegate protocols. Take iOS's `UITableViewDelegate` for example: here is a set of the delegate protocol's methods that define views for a table view's section headers and footers:

- `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`
- `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`
- `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`
- `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:`

If these are not implemented by the delegate, UIKit simply draws the default section headers and footers for the given `tableView`, that come pre-packaged with the default `UITableView` element. However, if they are implemented, UIKit uses the custom section header and footer views that are supplied by these methods with the `tableView`.

The `@optional` keyword pretty much tells the *person* writing a class to implement the delegate that these methods are optional. I believe UIKit does `conformsToProtocol:` and `respondsToSelector:` checks internally anyway.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock. I understand the value of maybe implementing the method and maybe not. But I don't understand what defining it in the protocol actually does, if I'm going to need to call respondsToSelector anyway.

Comment: So, more for the people than for the machines you think?

Comment: It would be nice if defining those optional methods in the protocol would automatically add a stub if the method wasn't defined, so that you didn't havet to call respondsToSelector.

Comment: @morgancodes: Sometimes an object implementing the protocol doesn't want to implement an optional method (even just a do-nothing stub). This is often the case with delegates.

Comment: The delegation pattern is all about "things I'm willing to let you (the delegate) handle," but you rapidly come to the conclusion that not everything that COULD be delegated NEEDS to be delegated.  Having optional methods in the protocol is just a hint to the adopter; "You COULD implement these methods, but you don't have to." For those who say, 'we shouldn't have to check respondsToSelector,' I refer you to this idea: http://borkware.com/rants/agentm/elegant-delegation/

Comment: BoltClock missed the point of morgancodes's question, which I also am here to look for the answer to. Ah, I guess, to sum it up, if you write a protocol with optional methods, you STILL HAVE TO use "respondsToSelector" to see if the delegate actually implements the method, before calling the method on the delegate. (sorry for the caps). If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: An important point about @optional protocol methods.  When you have @optional methods, make sure that you use the `repondsToSelector:` method before assuming that the conformer to your protocol implements that method.  Otherwise, an **unrecognized selector sent to instance <memory address>** exception will be raised.

Answer (score 1):

The `@optional`/`@required` are not just for people - though that would be a good reason itself! - it is also for machines. The compiler, static analyzer, etc. can use them to determine whether a class implementing a `@protocol` has provided all the required methods, and determine which optional methods are provided.

Answer (score 0):

Also see Apple's [Communicating with Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html), which discusses delegates, protocols, and selectors. Though its listed under Mac OS X, most (if not all) appears to apply to iOS also.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another point to it -- before you can send a message with a particular name, a method with that name must be declared *somewhere* visible to the scope where it is used. (It doesn't have to be declared as a method of the particular type you are sending the message to -- that's a separate issue, of dynamic typing and static type checking. But it must be declared *somewhere* as a method to *some* class or protocol, even if you don't use that class or protocol at all.) This is due to the fact that the compiler must translate a message call to `objc_msgSend` or `objc_msgSend_stret` or `objc_msgSend_fpret` depending on the return type of the method; so the compiler must know the signature of the method.

So an optional protocol method serves that purpose of declaring the method; whereas if you didn't include that method declaration in the protocol, a caller might not be able to call that method, due to there not having been a declaration for it.

Answer (score 0):

Protocols are only there for documentation and compile time checking.  Once the program is running, the runtime does not know or care about what static types your objects have (excepting the case where the method returns a struct as mentioned by newacct).

You can do without having protocols at all except that then there is no compile time checking that a particular object has the methods required of it when passed to a particular API. You can declare all your objects as type `id` if you like, but that effectively turns off the compiler checking that any messages you send to them are implemented by the objects.  It also prevents you from using dot notation for properties.

Given that you have got protocols, once you declare an object as conforming to a protocol e.g.

```
id<MyProtocol> foo;
```

That immediately turns the method checks back on.  Without optional methods this means that

```
if ([foo respondsToSelector: @selector(myOptionalSelector)])
{
    [foo myOptionalSelector];
}
```

would flag a compiler warning.   Putting the @optional method in suppresses that warning as well as stopping the compiler from having to guess about the return and parameter types.

Comment: This is not strictly true; Protocols can be interacted with at run-time too. See the Objective-C runtime reference and methods such as +[NSObject conformsToProtocol:].

Answer (score 0):

I think the big difference is the way to call the method!

If you don't define a protocol, you need to use the method `performSelector:` to call an unknown method. It works, but in this case, we are limited with the number and the type of parameters of your method. Indeed, you can't give a non object parameter and you could pass no more than 2 parameters with `performSelector:withObject:withObject:`. If you want more arguments, you need use an array or a dictionary.

```
id<MyProtocol> myObj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
if([myObj respondsToSelector:@selector(aMethod:)]){
  NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First arg",[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],nil];
  [myObject performSelector:(@selector(aMethod:) withObject:args];
}
```

Otherwise, if you define a protocol with your optional method you just call it normally:

```
id<MyProtocol> myObj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
if([myObj respondsToSelector:@selector(aMethodWithFirstArg:second:third:)]){
  [myObject aMethodWithFirstArg:@"First arg" second:2 third:YES];
}
```

Same result, but i prefer the second one with the protocol!

Answer (score -1):

Morgancodes,

You do NOT have to call `respondsToSelector` for every method declared in the protocol if you use protocols for type checking as well. A simple explanation can be found [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html)

Frank

Comment: You still have to do it for optional definitions.